# Links on virtualhost with Xampp not working

Tags: wordpress, xampp, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a virtualhost on my machine for a wordpress project

I added this to the http-vhosts.conf in Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest"
ServerName myapplication.dev
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this line to the windows hosts file

```
127.0.0.1             myapplication.dev
```

And I added these lines in wp-config

```
define('WP_HOME','http://myapplication.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://myapplication.dev');
```

I also added a plugin to allow relative URLs across wordpress

However, when I access http://myapplication.dev, the first page of my website is there, but none of the links work ! They all send a 500 error page

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: You're right ! It said :
"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://myapplication.dev/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution thanks to this link : https://gist.github.com/JustThomas/141ebe0764d43188d4f2

I changed my .htaccess file

Before :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpressTest/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpressTest/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

After :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```